# Creating a CSV data table from a Color Histogram Plot

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple program to grab an image and plot its blue and green pixel histogram. I get the plot but I want to do some data science on the plots. Is there an easy way to convert the plot into a table either that I can copy and paste from or straight to a .csv?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread(file_path)
color = ('b','g')
for i,col in enumerate(color):
    histr = cv2.calcHist([img],[i],None,[256],[0,256])
    plt.plot(histr,color = col)
    plt.xlim([0,256])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.imread()` returns a numpy array which you can save to a file, by default in binary format. To get a CSV formatted text file, use the `sep` parameter:

```py
img.tofile('image.csv', sep=',')
```

See the [official documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) for more information.